# Objective C - Buttons won't trigger when placed in particular UIViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

This is a potentially embarrassing question, so go easy on my if I'm missing something obvious.

I have the following set up: 3 UIViews declared as properties, laid side by side in a scrollview (also a property). Over all of these I am placing a container (child of self.view), not defined as a property. In this container, I have three buttons, not defined as properties. The problem is that the buttons will only trigger when they are set up as children as follows:

self.view > buttons => works

self.view > container (not a property) => doesn't work

self.view > container (is a property) => doesn't work

I can't imagine why buttons wouldn't trigger when placed in a containing UIView. Code is shown below:

```
//now draw the left panel:
panel1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.screenWidth,self.screenHeight)];
panel1.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:totalTransparent];
[self.scrollView addSubview:panel1];

//now draw the middle panel:
panel2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.screenWidth,0,self.screenWidth,self.screenHeight)];
panel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.scrollView addSubview:panel2];

//now draw the right panel:
panel3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.screenWidth*2,0,self.screenWidth,self.screenHeight)];
panel3.backgroundColor = [BGColor colorWithAlphaComponent:bgAlpha2];
[self.scrollView addSubview:panel3];

//bottom three buts
UIView *bottomButs = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, self.screenHeight - 1 - blockHeight, self.screenWidth - 2, blockHeight)];
bottomButs.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:blackTransparent];
[self.view addSubview:bottomButs];

UIButton *botButMusic = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[botButMusic addTarget:self action:@selector(goToPanel1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self activateButton:botButMusic];
botButMusic.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 104, buttonHeight);
botButMusic.backgroundColor = [buttonBGColor colorWithAlphaComponent:whiteTransparent];
[botButMusic setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3butMusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bottomButs addSubview:botButMusic];

UIButton *botButCamera = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[botButCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(goToPanel2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self activateButton:botButCamera];
botButCamera.frame = CGRectMake(106, 1, 105, buttonHeight);
botButCamera.backgroundColor = [buttonBGColor colorWithAlphaComponent:whiteTransparent];
[botButCamera setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3butCamera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bottomButs addSubview:botButCamera];

UIButton *botButWatch = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[botButWatch addTarget:self action:@selector(goToPanel3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self activateButton:botButWatch];
botButWatch.frame = CGRectMake(212, 1, 105, buttonHeight);
botButWatch.backgroundColor = [buttonBGColor colorWithAlphaComponent:whiteTransparent];
[botButWatch setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3butWatch.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bottomButs addSubview:botButWatch];
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is userInteractionEnabled = true for all superviews?

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't set userInteractionEnabled = FALSE anywhere, but explicitly setting it to TRUE fixed my problem. Is it not TRUE by default?

Comment: It depends on the class. For a UIView it is defaulted to YES, but for a UIImageView it is defaulted to NO. From the UIView documentation "Some UIKit subclasses override this property and return a different default value." You can check the documentation for specifics for each class. If this solution is adequate please mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like that was your problem with the line. UIView *bottomButs = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, self.screenHeight - 1 - blockHeight, self.screenWidth - 2, blockHeight)];

Comment: It's amazing what a fresh pair of eyes can do sometimes. Thanks for your help!